# Match first and then all equal occurrences with regex

Tags: regex

Lets say we have the string:

> one day, when Anne, Lisa and Paul went to the store, then Anne said to Paul: "I love Lisa!". Then Lisa laughed and kissed Anne.

**is there a way with regex to match the first name, and then match and all other occurrences of the same name in the string?**

Given the name-matching regex `/[A-Z][a-z]+` (with `/g` maybe?), can the regex matcher be made to remember the first match, and then use that match EXACTLY for the rest of the string? Other subsequent matches to the name-matching regex should be ignored (except for Anne in the example).

The result would be (if matches are replaced with "Foo"):

> one day, when Foo, Lisa and Paul went to the store, then Foo said to Paul: "I love Lisa!". Then Lisa laughed and kissed Foo.

Please ignore the fact that the sentence start uncapitalized, or add an example that also handles this.

Using a script to get the first match and then using that as input for a second iteration works of course, but that's outside the scope of the question (which is limited to ONE regex expression).

Comment: What is the tool or language? Do you also want to replace the first word if is does not occur in the sentence? In Javascript you might use `(?<=^([A-Z][a-z]*\b).*?)\1|^([A-Z][a-z]*\b)(?=.*\2)` See https://regex101.com/r/JgWYSQ/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I don't want it to be locked to starting at the beginning of the line, I'll edit the example :) But otherwise it seems to be on the right track...

Comment: So how will you know that the word is `Anne`?

Comment: @Thefourthbird I wont, the point is to get the first name (whatever it may be) and then only match occurrences of that exact name. If you swap Lisa and Anne in the text it should match Lisa because it's first, and then all other Lisas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I could think of is with non-fixed width lookbehinds. For example through Pypi's regex module, and maybe Javascript too? Either way, assuming a name is capture through `[A-Z][a-z]+` as per your question try:

```
\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b(?<=^[^A-Z]*\b\1\b.*)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/S8oOI3/1)

---

- `\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b` - A 1st capture group capturing a name between two word-boundaries;
- `(?<=^[^A-Z]*\b\1\b.*)` - A non-fixed width positive lookbehind to match start of line anchor followed by 0+ characters other than uppercase followed by the content of the 1st capture group and 0+ characters.

---

Here is a PyPi's example:

```
import regex as re

s= 'Anne, Lisa and Paul went to the store, then Anne said to Paul: "I love Lisa!". Then Lisa laughed and kissed Anne.'
s_new = re.sub(r'\b([A-Z][a-z]+)\b(?<=^[^A-Z]*\b\1\b.*)', 'Foo', s)
print(s_new)
```

Prints:

```
Foo, Lisa and Paul went to the store, then Foo said to Paul: "I love Lisa!". Then Lisa laughed and kissed Foo.
```